# I can't Image Upload Media in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, developer-tools

I can't solve this problem anyone help me emergency....!

[image]

WordPress shows this message i uploade an image in any place but the image does not uploade.
I saw the name of the image shorted, I saw the image with a smaller size, but it does not work.
[image]

Comment: Did you check your hosting/server disk space? Maybe the disk is full so Wordpress can't proceed to upload the file.

Comment: What's the file size of the image you're attempting to upload? What's the pixel size? Have you tried with other image files - is the issue specific to this particular file? Are you self-hosting your wordpress server?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you tell it otherwise, and since version 5.3 WordPress will not allow uploads larger than 2560 pixels.
You can update your PHP configuration by changing upload_max_filesize in php.ini to a higher value and try again.

If it still doesn't work, you may compress your image to a lower weight.